# Developing an extension for internet explorer 11 right now

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, atl, npapi, bho

I would like to develop an extension of Internet Explorer to export methods that can be called from JavaScript code. That's my only goal. I don't need toolbars or super privileges.

I created an ATL project after a good but old tutorial and the extension is properly installed and recognized by the browser. However, I do not know how to define a MIME type for that extension. In firefox I've developed an NPAPI plugin and work well for me, it define a mimetype, and an object tag can refer to it, for example:

```
<object id="myobject" type="application/x-mymime" visibility: hidden;> </object>
<script> 
   document.getElementById('myobject').myMethodInNPAPI();
   //I would like to do something like this:
   document.getElementById('myobject').myMethodInIEextension();
</script>
```

IE11 browser should be the navigator, and the OS can have 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: Basically you just need to map your mimetype to the CLSID of your activex control.  Take a look at the firebreath project (http://firebreath.org) and see how they do it.  Or you could just use firebreath, since it does what you want and works with NPAPI as well...

Comment: ok, let me check that, thanks